# SQL Server: IF EXISTS ; ELSE

Tags: sql, sql-server, if-statement, exists

I have a tableA:

```
ID value
 1  100
 2  101
 2  444
 3  501
```

Also TableB

```
ID Code
1
2
```

Now I want to populate col = code of table B if there exists ID = 2 in tableA. for multiple values , get max value.
else populate it with '123'. Now here is what I used:

```
if exists (select MAX(value) from #A where id = 2)
 BEGIN
 update #B
 set code = (select MAX(value) from #A where id = 2)
 from #A
 END

 ELSE 

 update #B
 set code = 123
 from #B
```

I am sure there is some problem in BEGIN;END or in IF EXIST;ELSE.
Basically I want to by-pass the else part if select statement in IF-part exist and vice- versa. For example if select statement of IF=part is:

```
(select MAX(value) from #A where id = 4)
```

It should just populate 123, coz ID = 4 do not exist !

Answer (score 106, accepted):

**EDIT**

I want to add the reason that your `IF` statement seems to not work. When you do an `EXISTS` on an aggregate, it's always going to be `true`. It returns a value even if the `ID` doesn't exist. Sure, it's `NULL`, but its returning it. Instead, do this:

```
if exists(select 1 from table where id = 4)
```

and you'll get to the `ELSE` portion of your `IF` statement.

---

Now, here's a better, set-based solution:

```
update b
  set code = isnull(a.value, 123)
from #b b
left join (select id, max(value) from #a group by id) a
  on b.id = a.id
where
  b.id = yourid
```

This has the benefit of being able to run on the entire table rather than individual ids.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
Update TableB Set
  Code = Coalesce(
    (Select Max(Value)
    From TableA 
    Where Id = b.Id), 123)
From TableB b
```

Answer (score 0):

I know its been a while since the original post but I like using CTE's and this worked for me:

```sql
WITH cte_table_a
AS
(
    SELECT [id] [id]
    , MAX([value]) [value]
    FROM table_a
    GROUP BY [id]
)
UPDATE table_b
SET table_b.code = CASE WHEN cte_table_a.[value] IS NOT NULL THEN cte_table_a.[value] ELSE 124 END
FROM table_b
LEFT OUTER JOIN  cte_table_a
ON table_b.id = cte_table_a.id
```